# How to display mysql data in different HTML elements by using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm new to web development and I'm following a couple of tutorials. I'm learning that how to display mySQL data into HTML by using HTML, PHP, jQuery and AJAX. Below example is my practice work where I'm successfully loading data into HTML table.

```
<table id="main" border="1px" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="header">
            <h1>PHP with AJAX</h1>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="table-form">
        <form id="addform">
            Student First Name: <input type="text" id="st-first-name">&nbsp;
            Student Last Name: <input type="text" id="st-last-name">

            <input type="submit" value="Save Data" id="save-data"><br>
        </form>
        
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="table-data">
            <table border="1px" width="100" cellspacing="0px" cellpadding="10px">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center">1</td>
                    <td>Abid Durrani </td>
                </tr>                          
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is my AJAX Code.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
        function loadData(){
            $.ajax({
                url: "ajaxload.php",
                type: "post",
                success: function(data){
                    $("#table-data").html(data);
                }        
            }); 
        } });
```

And this is my ajaxload.php code:

```
$myConn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test") or die("Your Connection Failed");
$sqlQuery = "select * from students";
$result = mysqli_query($myConn, $sqlQuery) or die ("Your Query Execution Failed");
$output = "";

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
$output = "
        <table border='2' cellpadding='5px' cellspacing='5px'>
        <tr>
            <th width='100px'>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th width='100px'>Delete</th>
        </tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            $output .= "    
            <tr>
                <td>{$row['st_id']}</td>
                <td>{$row['st_first_name']}</td>
                <td><button class='btn-delete' data-myid={$row['st_id']}>Delete</button></td>
            </tr>"; 
        }
        $output .= "</table>";

    mysqli_close($myConn);
    echo $output;
} else
{
echo "sorry, no record found";
}
```

**Question:** Here my data is directly loading into HTML table through its css ID. What I want is to set my database data into a textBox and a dropDownMenu along with this table. For table, I've created the table in ajaxload.php but what do I need to do for dropDownMenu and textBox?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to echo the appropriate HTML in just the same way as you do for the table. Where exactly are you stuck with that? It's hard to give a specific answer with code as we don't know where you want to put these items relative to the rest of your page or what data you want to put into them, or what label you want next to them. Describe the problem more specifically please, and explain what is confusing you about the task

Comment: Thank you ADyson
In my php code I've echoed $output variable. And in my AJAX code I'm receiving that in success function(data). This data is then assigned to Table Element. If i have multiple echo's in my PHP code e.g. $output1, $output2, so I how do I receive them in single success function?

Comment: The whole output will be received in the one success variable. It doesn't matter how many separate echo statements you issue in the same script, it all comes back to JavaScript as a single piece of output - because the whole data is sent back to browser when the script is finished, not one piece at a time

Comment: Thank you very much.
Very well then.
Once, If I echoed more than 1 statements in my PHP code to Success function, then how would I separate them in AJAX and separately assign each to desired HTML element?

Comment: You want each part in a different place in your page, not all together, you mean? It would help us if you could give specifics

Comment: Yes thats what I mean.

Comment: I want that when my query fetch the database result, so it should be placed on my page in different HTML element e.g. some data to show in DropDownMenu, some in TextField, some in Table etc.
Thanks

Comment: If they are all to be consecutive on the page you can output the HTML for those all in one lump. If not, then maybe we need a different solution As I said before, give an exact example of what the final result should be. Then we can give the best advice.